# Computational complexity of base conversion

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, time-complexity, radix

What is the complexity of converting a very large n-bit number to a decimal representation?

My thought is that the elementary algorithm of repeated integer division, taking the remainder to get each digit, would have `O(M(n)log n)` complexity, where `M(n)` is the complexity of the multiplication algorithm; however, the division is not between 2 n-bit numbers but rather 1 n-bit number and a small constant number, so it seems to me the complexity could be smaller.

Comment: @xdavidliu: There is no need to spend O(M(n)) time to compute the quotient and remainder of a large integer by 10.  Linear time suffices.

Comment: @tmyklebu never mind, yes that is correct

Answer (score 4):

Naive base-conversion as you described takes quadratic time; you do about `n` bigint-by-smallint divisions, most of which take time linear in the size of the n-bit bigint.

You can do base conversion in O(M(n) log(n)) time, however, by picking a power of target-base that's roughly the square root of the to-be-converted number, doing divide-and-remainder by it (which can be done in O(M(n)) time via Newton's method), and recursing on the two halves.

Comment: I guess my question is whether or not division by a small number can be done in linear time O(n) or less. For example, division by 2 or 4 is trivially O(1); is there an O(n) algorithm for division by 10?

Comment: how is division by 2 O(1)? youll have to shift all bits, no?

Comment: @Tanner, yes, division by any fixed divisor is O(n), where n is the length of the dividend. Just use the usual long division algorithm. Allowing arbitrary divisors changes things.

Comment: @G.Bach, I think the idea there is that if you're representing the number as a little-endian list of bits, you can divide by 2 using `drop 1`.

Comment: @xdavidliu: I don't follow.  Do you have an algorithm for computing the product of two n-bit numbers that does not need to examine at least a constant fraction of the bits of the input, or write at least a constant fraction of the bits of the output?

Comment: @tmyklebu (I just deleted my comment, which was not correct) I incorrectly assumed that all divisions, even ones at deeper recursive levels, act on a single word of the top-level n, so take M(n) time, even for inputs of size n/2, n/4, etc. In fact, the divisions are deeper levels act on smaller input sizes, which was not clear to me.

Comment: Anyone have a link to a paper or implementation of this `O( M(n) log(n) )` algorithm?

Comment: @Meekohi try [this link](http://maths-people.anu.edu.au/~brent/pd/rpb032.pdf), page 14