# How to convert a large string number (uint256) into vector<unsigned char> in C++

Tags: c++, boost, bignum

I have a string number ranging in `uint256`, such as `"115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935"`.  I want to store the bytes of this number into a `vector<unsigned char>`. That is, I want to get `0xffffff...fff` (256bit) stored in the `vector`, where the `vector`'s size will not be larger than 32 bytes.

I have tried the following ways:

1. Using `int` to receive the string number and transfer, but the number is out of the `int` range;
2. Using `boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::cpp_int_backend<256, 256, boost::multiprecision::unsigned_magnitude, boost::multiprecision::unchecked, void>>`. But I do not know how to transfer the string number to this type. I cannot find the details of using this type on the Internet.

Comment: A possible solution might be to first convert the long decimal number into the corresponding hexadecimal value, still as a string. Once you have the hexadecimal representation in a string, it's easy to convert every two digits into a byte-sized integer value to store in the vector.

Comment: You just construct the boost number from a string, or  stream with >>.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude However, in the procedure of converting the decimal string number to the hex string number, a large integer type must be needed to receive the decimal string for converting. Then it returns back to the initial problem.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem Could you please detail it in the answer?

Comment: in c# but the algorithm is the same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652760/how-to-convert-a-gi-normous-integer-in-string-format-to-hex-format-c/18231860#18231860, also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45262037/algorithm-for-converting-large-hex-numbers-into-decimal-form-base-10-form

Comment: `0xffffff...fff` is 256 bits, not 255

Comment: @phuclv Sorry. I updated the question.

Comment: If this is the *only* multiple / extended precision algorithm needed, dependency on a multiple precision library will be more effort than a robust, one-time conversion function. Consider semantics similar to: [std::stoul](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul); Furthermore - if other multiple-precision integer arithmetic operations are required, consider GMP and its [C++ interface](https://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Class-Interface) rather than the over-engineered [dependency hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell) of the Boost libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Boost.Multiprecision-based solution worked for me well:

```
std::string input { "115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935" };

boost::multiprecision::uint256_t i { input };

std::stringstream ss;
ss << std::hex << i;
std::string s = ss.str();
std::cout << s << std::endl;

std::vector<unsigned char> v{s.begin(), s.end()};
```

It prints:

```
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
```

Is it what you are looking for?

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/cW1hf61Wf.

**EDIT**

I might have originally misunderstood the question. If you want the vector to contain the binary representation of that number (that is to serialize that number into a vector), it is also possible, and even easier:

```
std::string input{ "115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935" };
boost::multiprecision::uint256_t i { input };
    
std::vector<unsigned char> v;
export_bits(i, std::back_inserter(v), 8);
```

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/c1GvfndG9.

Corresponding documentation: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/import_export.html.

Comment: And if OP wants to export the bits instead, there's [export_bits](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/import_export.html).

Comment: @DanielLangr Thanks very much! Your solutions address my problem perfectly!!